# Display number int in Python

Tags: python

How to display numbers integer in python ?
For example:

```
number1 = raw_input('Write one number:  ')
number2 = raw_input('Write other number: ')
result =  number1 + number2
print "The sum of the numbers is: %d" % result # here, display the result of the operatio n.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot the all that responded!

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer you feel best helped you get to your solution!

Answer (score 3):

You want

```
result = int(number1) + int(number2)
```

raw_input returns strings.

Answer (score 1):

`raw_input` returns strings.  If you mean for them to be integers, then use `int(x)` to convert them to ints.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the inputted strings into numbers:

```
result = int(number1) + int(number2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this;

```
In [1]: numstr="5"

In [2]: int(numstr)
Out[2]: 5
```

So in your code `result = int(number1) + int(number2)`

You'd want to do some input sanitation check though. Users have a bad habit of making mistakes.